# Sort Associations by its Values (which are nested lists)

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, sorting

I have associations where the values are nested lists:

```
assoclist= <|KeyA -> {{a,b,2},{c,d,4},{e,f,3}}, 
KeyB -> {{a,b,1},{c,d,4},{e,f,6}}, KeyC -> {{a,b,2},{c,d,6},{e,f,9}}|>;
```

Now I need to sort the associations by the total sum of the third elements (here the numbers) in each list so that Key C comes first (total sum = 17), than Key B (11) and Key A (9).

How can I do this?

Comment: `SortBy[assoclist, -Total[#[[All, 3]]]&]`? (Or use `ReverseSortBy` and get rid of the minus sign)

Comment: @SjoerdSmit: I have tried this before but it did not work. It must have been a typing error or so. However now it works perfectly, thx!

Answer (score 6):

You may use `ReverseSortBy` with `Total` and `Composition`.

```
ReverseSortBy[Last@*Total]@assoclist
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Beautiful use of the Wolfram Language.  The absence of specific list indices is very nice.  It is also easily extended by changing Last or Total as needed.

Answer (score 4):

E.g:

```
assoclist[[Reverse[Ordering[Total[assoclist[[All, All, 3]]]]]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

With Transpose:

```
assoclist // 
  Map[Transpose] // 
  ReverseSortBy[Total@*Last] // 
  Map[Transpose]
```